# Can you make a 3d matrix from one 2d matrix repeated a set number of times?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a greyscale function.  The function takes a 3D matrix, which consists of RBG values for each pixel, and returns another 3D matrix which represents a 3D image.  I got it to work with this code

```
function [ gray ] = convertImageToGrayscale(orig)

    page = 0.299*orig(:,:,1) + 0.587*orig(:,:,2) + 0.114*orig(:,:,3);

    gray(:,:,1) = page;
    gray(:,:,2) = page;
    gray(:,:,3) = page;

end
```

Each RBG value must be the same, and the "page" variable saves what they should be at each pixel.  The next three lines create a gray image with the new RGB intensities.

Is there a faster way to make that gray matrix?  Perhaps a way go through each page of the gray matrix and replace it with my "page" variable.  I'm not supposed to use loops, so it there is a way to vectorize this code that would be useful to me.

Comment: Do you really need the replication? In matlab a grayscale image is typically [n m 1] not [n m 3]. Just try it with only the first line.

Comment: You could try using the concatenation operation to get the 3d matrix

Comment: gray = cat (3, page, page, page) could work

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gray = repmat( page, [1 1 3] );
```